# Не могу получить доступ к элементу List?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Есть следующий класс

```
public class OneDay
{
    public int Nomber { get; set; }        
    public List<int> Arr = new List<int>();
}
```

Далее создаю list с его экземплярами, заполняю и привязываю к ListBox

```
public List<OneDay> Days = new List<OneDay>();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++)
    {
        Days.Add(new OneDay());
        Days[Days.Count - 1].Nomber = i + 1;
        for(int j = 0; j<4; j++)
        {
            Days[Days.Count - 1].Arr.Add(10+j);
        }
    listOfDays.ItemsSource = Days;
}
```

В xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listOfDays" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>                                    
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent" >
                <Label Background="Red" Content="{Binding Nomber}"></Label>
                <Label Background="Blue" Content="{Binding Arr[0]}"></Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>     
</ListBox>
```

В ListBox в красных Label отображается номер каждого дня из листа Days, а синих label Arr[0] не выводится. В чем ошибка? И как тогда получить элемент коллекции через Binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Привязка в XAML работает только для свойств. В приведённом примере List является не свойством, а полем:

```
public class OneDay
{
    public int Nomber { get; set; }        
    public List<int> Arr = new List<int>();
}
```

Попробуйте заменить на

```
public List<int> Arr { get; set; }
```

и инициализировать в конструкторе.
Также в новом C# есть inlnie-инициализация для свойств:

```
public List<int> Arr { get; set; } = new List<int>();
```